# Entity Framework - inserts a new row after update

Tags: entity-framework

let's say that I have a row in my table:

```
| ID | Name       |
|  1 | file1.doc  |
```

and I want to update the Name column in that row, so I use that code:

```
public partial class Adapter
{
    private my_Entities _db = null;

    public my_Entities db
    {
        get
        {
            if (_db == null) _db = new my_Entities();
            return _db;
        }
    }

    public Orders GetOrderByID(int id)
    {
        return (from x in db.Orders
                where x.ID == id
                select x).FirstOrDefault();
    }
 }

 Adapter adapter = new Adapter();

 var order = adapter.GetPublishOrderByID(123);

 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //< 2 is just for test, the purpose of the whole code is to append the FileName if any file exist for the order
 {
    var existingFile = order.Files.FirstOrDefault();

   //here I get the information about entries
   var objectStateEntries = adapter.db.ObjectStateManager.
                         GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | 
                                               EntityState.Modified | 
                                               EntityState.Unchanged);


   if (existingFile  != null)
   {
     //now, in the objectStateEntries I can see that ont item with the Added state,
     //and the another entity with the Modified state.
     //They're poining at the same entity (the same ID)

      existingFile.FileName = "lorem.doc";   //FileName is 'file1.doc'    
   }
   else
   {
      order.P_CoverOptionalTempFiles.Add(new P_Files{ FileName = "file1.doc" });
      //the row's State is Added
   }

   adapter.db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and now in my DB I see two rows

```
| ID | Name       |
|  1 | file1.doc  |
|  2 | lorem.doc  |
```

why ?

Comment: Normally it shouldn't happen... So what is `order.Files` and `adapter.db`? Maybe you are having multiple contexts and retrieve from one context and saving in the other...

Comment: So the new row really has an ID of 1 as well?  If so, you'll want to make that ID column the Primary Key.  I'm not sure if that will fix this issue, but I did notice the repeated ID.

Comment: Gromer: it was my mistake, sorry

Comment: nemesv: `order.Files` are rows from table `Order` and `Files` (that tables are connected via FK) adapter.db - `adapter` is a class returning my `ObjectContext` via singleton

Comment: You have to pull from the same context or it will detect that they are different.

Comment: hmm I'm using the singleton pattern so it must be the same context. If no, what should I do in that case ?

Comment: You must show the code that loads/creates the `order.Files` collection.

Comment: You don't load the `order.Files` collection in your query. Does it get filled by lazy loading?

Comment: Slauma: yes, it is. I've also checked the State property of that entry and it is Added. See my edited question

Comment: Just as a test: Can you try to use eager loading `from x in db.Orders.Include("Files")...` and see if the problem is the same?

Comment: Slauma: Yes, it remained. That problem exist if that code is in the loop (see the edited question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, I had to dynamically create the context. Good to know in the future. But I'm still wondering why the previous code causes that problem...

```
var order = adapter.GetPublishOrderByID(123);

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   using(my_Entities ctx = new my_Entities)
   {
        //now, instead of the adapter.db I use ctx
   }
}
```